# Recognizing patterns in a data set

Tags: python, classification, image-recognition

I have a huge data set of images which I want to sort. Many images are just random noise which I don't need, but some of them contain patterns which I would like to process further.

Here is an example:
[image]

Here, the patterns are looking like lines. Which possibilities do I have to keep only the pictures which contain a kind of pattern?

Comment: Which possibilities? By processing the images I'd say. Hope that answers your question. *(Hint: This is a very vague incomplete question IMO)*. On a more serious note, pick up PIL or another image processing library and get cracking.

Comment: Use a bank of (linear) filters with them and filter those ones that have experimented any response?

Comment: @Torxed Is there a way to measure the information in the images to find out which of these images contain structures? Pure noise should have less information compared to images with pattern. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're most likely looking for a average comparison of color values etc. But if you're asking me to show you how it's done. I revert back to, get started, and we can help out when you bump into a problem. Coding the entire solution or recommending libraries are usually not recommended here. This question, as it is now, is to broad.

Comment: Hough Transform is a great technique for finding straight lines in an image.

Comment: @dobkind I read about the Hough transform. It interesting, but I do not see how I can use it. I would need a value for every image such that I can distinguish random noise from images with patterns. But what I read is that it returns coordinates for lines. How can I use it for my problem?

Comment: @Samuel The result of the transform is stored in a matrix, where each entry represents a line. If you find in this matrix one or more 'bright' spots (i.e., cells with value higher than some threshold), that image probably contains a line. In addition, I would also suggest considering the intensity of each pixel in the image in order to weight its 'vote', as it can be seen that the values of the straight line are significantly higher.

Answer (score 1):

You have a classification problem (structures vs noise). As some people said in the comments, this is a very vague and broad question, like a starting question in an image processing or pattern recognition course. However, I will try to explain how this could work, assuming you have no background on the topics.

First, you need to get some features or parameters from the images, then identify how the values of the features are related with noisy images and structured images.

In practical terms, you need to read the images files and convert them into values, in order to process them and try a classification method.

***This is an example that could or could not work:***

As shown by the images you provided, your images are black and white, and suppose that after import them, they have values from 0 (black) to 255 (white). Assuming they are 40 x 40 pixels, a simple feature I could think is the average of the pixel values.

I see the *patterns* are white lines, so I would say that the average of these images would be higher than the average of noisy images, which don't have white pixels. Then, you could find that average for noisy images could be for example [110, 100, 112, 98] and the average for images with patterns could be [130, 135, 125, 131]. If this is the case, you can use a threshold as a classification method. For example, if the average is greater than 125, the image is considered to contain a pattern, otherwise, it is noise.

If using the average is not enough to separate the classes, you should use more elaborated features, in this case you need to use some image processing, machine learning or any other approach that could fit your requirements